# Exterior tensor product of structure sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I am reading the book "Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry" by Daniel Huybrechts and to solve one of its questions, I came up to show that
$$\mathcal{O}_{X_1}\boxtimes\mathcal{O}_{X_2}=\mathcal{O}_{X_1\times X_2}$$
i.e.
$${\pi_{X_1}}^*\mathcal{O}_{X_1}\otimes{\pi_{X_2}}^*\mathcal{O}_{X_2}=\mathcal{O}_{X_1\times X_2}$$ where here $\pi_{X_1}$ (resp. $\pi_{X_2}$) is the projection from $X_1\times X_2\to X_1$ (resp. $X_1\times X_2\to X_2$) and I am looking at $\mathcal{O}_{X_1}$,  $\mathcal{O}_{X_2}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X_1\times X_2}$ as objects in $D^b(X_1)$, $D^b(X_2)$ and $D^b(X_1\times X_2)$, respectively. My question is that is this equality true and if yes, why?

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the fact that for any $\pi: Y\to X$ we have $\pi^* \mathcal O_X \cong \mathcal O_Y$? This holds for sheaves and I would assume on the level of derived categories as well.

Comment: @TabesBridges I do not know if it is true on the level of derived categories.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The way you compute a derived pullback is to take a flat resolution and then pull that back, but the structure sheaf is trivially flat and pulls back to the structure sheaf.